# Selecting newest distinct email address from table

Tags: mysql

Very quick one:

I've done this before, but having a bit of a mind blank right now.

```
SELECT max(id) as id, username, email 
FROM user_info 
WHERE username!='' 
GROUP by id,email
```

Unfortunately this is not working. It will select the max id but not then the corresponding data from that row.

Comment: is `id` a primary key? auto_increment int? grouping on it like that will essentially undo the grouping.

Comment: Do you want only 1 row in the result or 1 per distinct email?

Comment: Then use @bluefeet's (2nd) query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If you have multiple ids per email address, then you can use `max(id)` and group by the email only.</strike>

```
SELECT max(id) as id, username, email 
FROM user_info 
WHERE username <> '' 
GROUP by email, username
```

You can use a subquery which will return the max id in the subquery and then you use that to self join on the table to return the most recent id, username and email:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email 
FROM user_info u
INNER JOIN
(
  select max(id) maxid, email
  from user_info
  where username <> '' 
  group by email
) u2
  on u.id = u2.maxid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/100a2/1)

Comment: This will select the username of the wrong row unfortunately. I need to basically select distinct email addresses and the highest id rows info with this email.

Comment: Then you should also group by the username

Comment: Won't work as your not pointing to the newest row. I have tested it, it gets a previous records username.

Comment: That's the one. Thought it would probably require a sub query. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DISTINCT(email), MAX(id)
FROM user_info
GROUP by email
ORDER BY id DESC
```